# How do I prove the following formula for $n$-th fibonacci number?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I was solving competitive coding questions, when I read [this discussion (via codeforces.com)](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18292) about efficiently calculating the nth term of a fibonacci series. Here is the relevant comment:

> Think about the formula... 
> $$F_i \;=\; F_{i-1} + F_{i-2} \;=\; 2F_{i-2} + F_{i-3} \;=\; 3F_{i-3}+2F_{i-4} \;=\;\cdots$$
> If you keep on with the formula, assuming $F_0 = 1$ and $F_1 = 1$, you'll reach a point where
>
> $$F_i = \begin{cases} 
> (F_{i/2})^2 + (F_{(i/2) - 1})^2 & \text{if $i$ is even}\\[0.5em]
> F_{\lceil i/2 \rceil} F_{\lfloor i/2 \rfloor} + F_{\lfloor i/2 \rfloor} F_{\lfloor (i/2)\rfloor - 1} & \text{if $i$ is odd}
> \end{cases}$$

However, I am unable to deduce how he came up with the formula. I did break down the original formula for Fibonacci numbers further but can't see any way to reduce this to $n/2$-th term.

If someone could shed light on this I would be quite thankful.

Answer (score 5):

**Claim.** For $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$F_{2n}=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad F_{2n+1}=F_nF_{n+1}+F_nF_{n-1}. $$

*Proof:* For $n=1$,
$$ F_{2}=2 = 1^1+1^2=F_1^2+F_0^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad F_3=3=1\cdot 2+1\cdot 1=F_1F_2+F_2F_0.$$
For an induction step,
$$ \begin{align}F_{2(n+1)}&=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}\\
&=(F_nF_{n+1}+F_nF_{n-1})+(F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2)
\\&= F_nF_{n+1}+(F_n+F_{n-1})F_{n-1}+F_n^2
\\&= F_nF_{n+1}+F_{n+1}F_{n-1}+F_n^2
\\&= (F_n+F_{n-1}F_{n+1}+F_n^2
\\&= F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}F_{2(n+1)+1}&=F_{2(n+1)}+F_{2n+1}\\
&=(F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2)+(F_nF_{n+1}+F_nF_{n-1})\\
&=(F_{n+1}+F_n)F_{n+1}+F_n(F_n+F_{n-1})\\
&=F_{n+2}F_{n+1}+F_nF_{n+1}\\
\end{align} $$
$\square$

Comment: Thanks for the proof. But isn't induction a non-constructive proof? Meaning we use it to check whether a given formula is correct or not. How can I deduce this particular formula for nth Fibonacci number?